# Текущие время + кнопка редактирование

Tags: reactjs

Я новичок в react и тут получается такая вот задача: дан текстареа и кнопка. В текстареа пользователь нашего сайта будет вводить свои заметки. После нажатия на кнопку введенный текст должен появится под текстареа в виде блока `div`. Таких заметок может быть много.

В каждой заметке должен стоять заголовок (заметка1, заметка2 и так далее), время создания заметки (часы, минуты, секунды), а также должна быть кнопка 'удалить' и кнопка 'редактировать'.

Проблема со временем. Почему то когда пишешь заметку, то секунды начинают двигаться, и в голове не укладывается что делать с кнопкой редактирование. Как ее реализовать? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот код:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor (props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {value: "",texts:[]}
  this.clock()
  }

  handleChange(event){
   this.setState({value: event.target.value})
  }

  addItem(){
   this.state.texts.push(this.state.value);
   this.setState({texts: this.state.texts});
   this.state.value ='';
  }
  deleteClick(num){
   this.state.texts.splice(num ,1);
   this.setState({texts: this.state.texts});
  }

  clock(){
   
    this.setState({
    time: (new Date()).toLocaleString()
    })
   
  }

  render(){
   const text = this.state.texts.map((item,index)=>{
    const date = new Date();
    const Time = (date.getHours() +':'+ date.getMinutes() +':'+ date.getSeconds());
    return <li key={index}>{item}<h4> Заметка {index+1}</h4> 
     <button onClick={this.deleteClick.bind(this,index)}>Delete</button>
     <button>edit</button>
     <p>{Time}</p>
    </li>
   })
   return(
    <div>
    <ul>{text}</ul>
     <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
     <button onClick={this.addItem.bind(this)}>Add</button>
     
    </div>
   );
  }

 }

 
  
const app = document.getElementById("content")
ReactDOM.render ( <App />, app);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас тут много что не понятного.... Вы часто меняете напрямую state. А это не желательно! Более того, вы храните только текст в массиве, а нужно и время и другую важную информацию.

Вот как пример:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
 constructor (props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {value: "",texts:{}}

 }

 handleChange(event){
  this.setState({value: event.target.value})
 }

 addItem(){
  let id = Date.now();
  const date = new Date();
  const Time = (date.getHours() +':'+ date.getMinutes() +':'+ date.getSeconds());
  this.setState({
   texts: {
    ...this.state.texts,
    [id]: {
     text: this.state.value,
     id: id,
     time: Time
    }
   },
   value: ''
  });
 }
 deleteClick(id){
  var new_state = Object.assign({}, this.state.texts);
  delete new_state[id];
  this.setState({
   texts: new_state
  });
  
 }
 editClick(id){
  var new_state = Object.assign({}, this.state.texts);
  new_state[id].text = '1231231231' 
  
      // тут конечно вы сделаете какой-ниубдь ещё textarea, получите значения и т.д....
      this.setState({
       texts: new_state
      });
      
    }


    render(){
     const text = Object.keys(this.state.texts).map((item,index)=>{
      const this_item = this.state.texts[item];
      
      return <li key={index}>{this_item.text}<h4> Заметка {index+1}</h4> 
      
      <button onClick={this.deleteClick.bind(this,this_item.id)}>Delete</button>
      <button onClick={this.editClick.bind(this,this_item.id)}>edit</button>
      <p>{this_item.time}</p>
      </li>
     })
     return(
     <div>
     <ul>{text}</ul>
     <textarea value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
     <button onClick={this.addItem.bind(this)}>Add</button>
     
     </div>
     );
    }

  }

  
  
  const app = document.getElementById("content")
  ReactDOM.render ( <App />, app);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

[код на codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKgJNX?editors=1010)

Там есть ещё что доработать. Но основная мысль такая: не менять state на прямую, хранить всю важную информацию о записи в state, а не формировать её при render'e

Comment: спасибо. то есть нужно как можно реже использовать state? И подскажите пожалуйста, что это за три точки `...this.state.texts`?

Comment: суть не в том чтобы РЕЖЕ использовать store, а в том, что бы там ничего не менять напрямую. Вот эта запись  this.state.texts.push(this.state.value); или эта this.state.value ='';  - меняет stor напрямую. Этого делать нельзя.

Comment: Три точки spread - по сути мы вернули все что есть в объекте, не трогая сам объект. Тут подробнее - https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring

Answer (score 0):

У вас возникает событие `onchange` каждый раз при изменении значения элемента формы.В функции `handleChange` вы обновляете состояние компонента,что приводит к вызову `render`.И `<p>{Time}</p>` берет значение отсюда `const Time = (date.getHours() +':'+ date.getMinutes() +':'+ date.getSeconds());`